# copy file from hdfs and rename if exists

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there any way to copy files from hdfs to local and rename it if it exists on the destination?
Like part-00000 , part-00000(1), part-00000(2)

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal  /user/output-*/RunTime/p*    Runtimes/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively, no.

You would need custom code to scan the destination files and see if

1. The filename exists, add `(1)`
2. Filename exists, and some file with the same name ending in `(n)`, make a new file with `(n+1)`

I would recommend you download the files into a timestamped folder instead so you aren't confused about which part files you're working with, and you can more easily see "part files over time"